# Find a nonregular 3-fold covering space of the genus two closed orientable surface.

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Find a nonregular 3-fold covering space of the genus two closed orientable surface.

This question was asked to me in Ph.D. Preliminary Exam. I have not any idea.

Comment: Silly answer: the disjoint union of $M$ and its orientated double cover.

Comment: @MikeMiller The orientation double cover of an orientable surface is just two disjoint copies of it, right? (Or do you mean that the covering should now preserve orientation or something...?) But following the silly train of thought, you could take a disjoint copy of M and its connected double cover (the orientable surface of genus 3).

Comment: @Max: I misread the question - thanks for the correction!